# Screen showing too slowly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, loading

I initialized my screen and all the elements in `viewDid` load, hidden them and set to reveal them after parsing JSON, I have a `collectionView` in a `scrollView` inside which I synchronically load elements that I dowloaded. Downloading and parsing JSON takes less than a sec, but for my screen to show up it takes a lot, but funny thing is when I try to scroll the screen it appears instantly, so I think that something is up with either `scrollView` or `collectionView` that I am not aware of. Anyone had a similar situation?

```
collectionView.dataSource = self is in the .hidden = false function
```

there is a lot of code, I am not sure that it would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried reload data after parsing JSON like 'collectionView.reloadData()'

Comment: yes i had those everywhere and it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new function to update your view's hidden elements
and then call it like :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@"your-selector" withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]
```

Because in async calls view updates won't be affective time-to-time.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

for swift it worked by wraping the func that unhides the elements just after parsing JSON with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.loadScreen()
            }
        })
```

thanx iremk for the objective c eqvivalent :)